# Openssl aes.h [Linker error] undefined reference to

Tags: c++, c, openssl, aes

I tried to make simple test program with AES decryption using OpenSSL ibaries. The compiler/linker shows me an error. Compiler: Dev-Cpp

```
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `AES_set_decrypt_key'
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `AES_decrypt'
```

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
int main(){
AES_KEY k;
unsigned char key[]="2641cf97291c6ea02b930a4e2a824990";
unsigned char in[]="adc8f4ad114433ffaf4597c9738d257c504db763c29d238aa05bd21e1107809f";
unsigned char out[150];

AES_set_decrypt_key(key, 256, &k);
AES_decrypt(in, out, &k);

printf("%s\n", out);

}
```

Tnx

Comment: Linker error means the compiler (well the linker actually) can't find the library.

Comment: You need to link against the OpenSSL libraries. Are you doing that?

Comment: Post the compilation command and output, please. Link against the libs by using the "-l" and "-L" compiler flags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should link against the openssl libraries - add this to your command line: `-lssl -lcrypto`

EDIT: you may have to specify explicitly where are the libraries located using the -L option - add a `-L<openssl_library_directory>` to the command as well

Comment: assuming the OP uses g++ or similar

Comment: He also needs to specify the path with -L like I put in my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718418/openssl-aes-h-linker-error-undefined-reference-to#comment13919875_10718418

Comment: @Brady - true I assume using linux where openssl is installed using apt-get

Comment: @Attila this is the usual case with devcpp

Comment: @izomorphius - true, missed that part of the post