# Can't fix unresolved external symbol _AES_encrypt even with lib files

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, openssl

I need to use openssl library for my encryption .

I read this threads :

- [Openssl aes.h [Linker error] undefined reference to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718418/openssl-aes-h-linker-error-undefined-reference-to)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

What I did :

1. Downloaded Pre-Compiled Library of OpenSSL for VS2012 from [here](https://github.com/David-Reguera-Garcia-Dreg/Precompiled-OpenSSL-Windows/tree/master/openssl-1.1.0e-vs2012) .
2. Added this addresses in :

   > General > Additional Include Directories : **openssl-1.1.0h\openssl-1.1.0f-vs2012\include**
   >
   > Linker > Additional Include Directories : **openssl-1.1.0h\openssl-1.1.0f-vs2012\lib**
3. I used Default sample of openssl but I get this errors :

> 1>AES_Encryption 2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _AES_set_encrypt_key 1>AES_Encryption 2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AES_decrypt 1>AES_Encryption 2.obj : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AES_encrypt 1>AES_Encryption
>   2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AES_set_decrypt_key

What i did wrong ?

edit : and here's my simple code :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

void main()
{
unsigned char inbuffer[1024];
unsigned char encryptedbuffer[1024];
unsigned char outbuffer[1024];

unsigned char oneKey[] = "abc";
AES_KEY key; 

AES_set_encrypt_key(oneKey,128,&key); /// error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AES_set_encrypt_key
getchar();

}
```

Comment: Post your code.  And linking to a duplicate question without explaining what makes your situation different isn't going to get you an answer, it's just going to get your question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewHenle code is simple , I have problem with linking openssl , Code added.

Comment: You need to put `#pragma comment(lib, "libssl.lib")` or something similar  (not sure about the name of the actuel .lib file) into your source file.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thank you sir , I added `#pragma comment(lib, "libcryptoMD.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libcryptoMDd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libcryptoMT.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libcryptoMTd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libsslMD.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libsslMDd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libsslMT.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libsslMTd.lib")` and it's working now . if you can please write it to a new answer I will mark it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your c file *compiles* fine, but it doesn't *link* correctly because you didn't instruct the linker to link with the necessary .lib files.

You need to put `#pragma comment(lib, "libssl.lib")` or something similar (not sure about the name of the actuel .lib file) into your source file.